# Need help avoid HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3 error

Tags: javascript, xml, backbone.js

I'm using javascript with backbone and adobe air. In my view model, I have a parse function where it saves the response( Dom object ), later on, when user hits saves, I want to add a couple of nodes to that saved response but I'm getting Dom exception 3, any help? Here are some code for reference.

```
parse: function(resp, xhr){
       this.treeDoc = xhr.responseXML
       //parse routine
      }
```

Somewhere down the road, when user wants to save

```
var xmlTree = createMyXML(); //creates a sub xml tree
this.treeDoc.appendChild(xmlTree ); //DOM Error 3 thrown
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely to have to call adoptNode first:

```
this.treeDoc.adoptNode(newElements);
```

Then append to a child node like:

```
this.treeDoc.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(newElements);
```

Additionally if `newElements` is an array of new elements(like the name suggest) you will need to iterate through it.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document for more info.

An answer to your comment(it was to large to be a comment it self):

Even if I didn't reproduce the error I think I know why you are getting it. Error 8 is the code for NOT_FOUND_ERR. Guess you save the value of `childNodes.length` and iterate from 0(zero) to this value, what happens here is that the `childNodes` array is updated every time a child is added or removed, and then in some point in your loop `i` is actually greater than `childNodes.length`(but not greater that the saved value) causing `childNodes[i]` to return `undefined`. And because `undefined` is not a child of the referenced node the NOT_FOUND_ERR (code 8) is throw. To avoid this with minor changes to the code just iterates for the initial value of `childNodes.length-1` to 0(zero), or just do:

```
while(node.childNodes.length > 0) node.removeChild(node.childNodes[0])
```

Comment: Hey thanks, also I get a DOM exceptino 8, when trying to remove a child for some reason, any idea on why? All i'm doing is getting the child elements and then for i = 0 to childElements.length, I call tree.remove(childElements[i])

Comment: Can't reproduce this, what browser you are using? And I guess by `childElements` you want to say `childNodes`, and by `remove` you want to say `removeChild`. Or maybe if you show more code.

Comment: Not really using browser, but using adobe air, but I think adobe air is based on safari web-kit

Comment: As for code, its something like this<pre><code> removeAllChild(doc,parent,childName){ var nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(childName); for(var child in nodes) parent.removeChild(child); }

Comment: Check the answer, I edited it soon after my last comment because it was too big for a comment.